# Redirection to base url with GET array in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to make the pagination work with the get parameter. Only that, the rest of the site will use uri.

The problem is this, as soon as I append ?something=zyx it redirects to the base url.

Config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-&=';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|lib|robots\.txt|upload)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks

EDIT: AFTER A LONG RESEARCH I FOUND THE PROBLEM.

I post it here in case somebody else has the same problem.

If you are planning to use GET vars in whatever form, even a hybrid solution like mine you must set:

$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";

in the config file.

Comment: Did you try doing enable_query_string setting to TRUE in you config..?

Comment: @Sudhir not what I want.. query string will override the normal uris, and that I don't want. I want a hybrid solution ONLY for pagination.

Comment: Why do you need query strings for the pagination? You can well do without it. Indeed, CI has also a pagination class which works nice without query strings

Comment: I agree with @DamienPirsy, there are better solutions the what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DamienPirsy I don't mean to sound rude, but I'm not asking how should I do better. I'm exploring my options, the problem with the pagination class (which I use) is that it doesn't manage associative uris, but only segments, it I'm on a page with several other uri paramenters it gets complicated. Beside my problem is that if I append a ?var=something to ANY page of my site I get redirected to the base_url() that was my question, not if I should or shouldn't do it. I may end up using uri, still I would love to know why it happens.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want to use query strings while using pagination, the following code should be enough:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

...
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
...

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

You should check the rest of the [Pagination Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) documentation.

Comment: No what I asked, my question was: "Why does I get redirected to my base url whenever I pass a GET parameter to any page of my website?"

Comment: In a comment, you said that you wanted a hybrid solution. Did you at least try out what I proposed? Downvote? Yeah, it seems about right...

Comment: yes already tried, as I said it was not what I asked at all, hence the (justified) downvote.

Comment: You could simply add a comment saying that my answer didn't work and I would gladly try to help you in other way, but with attitude, solve the problem yourself.